# mod_rewrite redirects to the CSS file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a mod_rewrite rule for cleaning up a URL:

```
RewriteRule ^tshirts*$ /thsirt.php
```

The idea is that visiting `myurl.com/tshirt` or `myurl.com/tshirts` should redirect to `myurl.com/tshirt.php`.

Visiting `myurl.com/tshirt` properly displayed `tshirt.php` until I added an external stylesheet link to `tshirt.php` - now it actually redirects to the CSS file, so I'm left with the raw source of the CSS file (`tshirt.css`).

And to make it even more confounding, if I navigate to `myurl.com/tshirts`, it throws a 404.

Source of `tshirt.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tshirt.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Source of `tshirt.css`:

```
body{
    background-color: #4F5557;
}
```

Any idea what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like your rewrite rule is matching your css file, try `RewriteRule ^tshirts/?$ /thsirt.php`

Comment: An easy solution would be to keep your CSS in other folders that won't match that rule, like "/resources" or "/css".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to cover all your bases, basically ensure you are only going to rewrite what you need to, and nothing that shouldn't be.

First, as a default, you should look to not rewrite anything that refers to either a specific file, or directory, using:

```
# Do Not apply if a specific file or folder exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Adding the following Next also allows you to specify certain directories to ignore rules for, that may be there for other purposes such as called scripts or resources to be linked to externally.

```
# Do Not apply if refering to a resource in one of these folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/admin/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/scripts/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/external/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

Then finally, you can have your rule/s

```
RewriteRule ^tshirts*$ /tshirt.php
```

Comment: That took care of it; thanks. However, going to `myurl.com/tshirts` still returns a 404 - any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would not want the urls of any existing files or directories to be rewritten, so before your rule you add 2 conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^tshirts*$ /thsirt.php
```

A clear folder structure for the different kind of resources also helps keeping your project manageable.